# Unable to create a logic to convert the values in Excel to CSV the right way with VBA

Tags: vba, excel

[image]I made the code to convert the values to the csv file but the problem is 
that I'm not sure if this is the right way because this is the first time I even touched VBA macro! As seen in the image I provided, there is a button "Convert to CSV", when I tap it, the macro will call ExportWorksheetAndSaveAsCSV method and will convert the entire sheets contents into csv. However, it looks like it converts the entire sheet it'self.

What I want to do is the following steps .
1.Pass in the Sheet name as a parameter like ExportWorksheetAndSaveAsCSV("Sheet2"), so that it can be used as a file name. But I'm not sure how I can pass  a parameter in function from the Buttton.

2.Convert the values in the columns E to I to CSV. If possible want to have the tites of the data show in the first row of the csv file.

I attached the image and the code so you can see. Some tips or examples will be really helpful! I would love to hear from you.

```
Public Sub ExportWorksheetAndSaveAsCSV()

Dim wbkExport As Workbook
Dim shtToExport As Worksheet
Dim book As String
Dim fileName As String

book = "Sheet1"
fileName = "test.csv"


Set shtToExport = ThisWorkbook.Worksheets(book)     'Export to CSV file
Set wbkExport = Application.Workbooks.Add
shtToExport.Copy Before:=wbkExport.Worksheets(wbkExport.Worksheets.Count)
Application.DisplayAlerts = False
wbkExport.SaveAs fileName:="C:\Users\myStuff\Documents\" & fileName, FileFormat:=xlCSV
Application.DisplayAlerts = True

wbkExport.Close SaveChanges:=False


End Sub
```

Comment: Excel doesn't create a 'valid' csv in that if any field contains a comma it will break the file. So if you have text fields that may have a comma in it, this method to create a CSV file will not work.

Comment: https://support.microsoft.com/en-ca/help/291296/procedure-to-export-a-text-file-with-both-comma-and-quote-delimiters-i

Comment: As seen in the image, there will be no comma inside any of the columns so I surmise it will not break, my biggest concern is how can I get to convert the data's in columns E to I and not from the entire file ?

Comment: You have to find some way to define the range. Once you know the range, I think if you select that you can then do the export. The code in the link above does that, you manually select the range but you can automate that step.

Comment: Do you know how to automate the step to check the range of the columns ?

Comment: @Reeza Are you sure Excel doesn't create a valid CSV file?  Every time I have done so, it has correctly wrapped cells containing commas with double-quotation marks.  It even wraps numbers formatted with commas as thousands separators (or as the decimal separator) in double-quotation marks - which I always find annoying.  (I would prefer it save the `Value` property of cells rather than the `Text` property.)

Comment: Pretty positive but it's easy enough to check that

Comment: @TimWilliams Just did, going to date myself here, appears to have been fixed as of Excel2010. Assuming you're working with 2010+ you're good to go. If you have line feeds that may still cause issues in other apps but otherwise appears fine.